# Trying to make VLC/Quicktime stop but loop

Tags: video, mac, vlc, quicktime

Really hoping to make this possible in VLC (2.1.0) or Quicktime (10.4) at a Mac:

1. Play (lets say) 5 films
2. Each film should stop playing at the end
3. Than by a so called hotkey the next film should start playing
4. At the end (number 5), it should start again at number 1
5. All in full screen

Is the possible? Reaaaally wanna know!!

And if not in VLC/Quicktime, in which player would it be possible? (and if I switch to PC?)

Very greatfull for any help!

Alan

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would involved writing a [bash script](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php), using a while loop waiting for inputs to stop.

```
while :
do
    vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_1.avi
    vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_2.avi
    vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_3.avi
    vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_4.avi
    vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_5.avi

done
```

If you hit CTLR+C, it will end the current video and start the next one.
To exit, you have to close the terminal. There might be a more elegant solution, like a while loop waiting for an input to stop.

### EDIT

one-liner that can be run in a terminal :

```
while :; do vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_1.avi;vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_2.avi;vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_3.avi;vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_4.avi;vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_5.avi;done
```

### Explanation

- **while :** equivalent to **while true**, infinite loop
- **-f** full screen option
- **--play-and-exit** exit vlc after playing vidéo

Comment: Thanx mxdsp for your answer! I feel like getting close, but also being a big noob..... I only came this far: [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/72puuo.jpg[/IMG] and I don't know how to make it actually work..... :S

Comment: I'm just to stupid to understand your answer, thanks though..! I'm breaking my head on this one... :(

I found this online:

In VLC Media Player:

Select Tools > Preferences
Select the Interface tab (default tab)
At the bottom of the Interface options, in the Playlist section, tick "Pause on the last frame of a video"
Click Save
Start playing the first video
It will pause once it reaches the end
To move on to the next video, hit n (next).
If you need to go back, hit p (previous)

BUT "Pause on the last frame of a video" doesn't exist anymore :(((( I even downgraded VLC, not working :( Anybody?

Comment: Hum. This is not an Ubuntu system on that picture ! I'm afraid you are out of topic here (and that i can't help you, because I never used a mac). But did you copy it to the end ? you are missing the ending ";done".  And you're not stupid, at all that command can't be very clear for a person with no experience in command line / programming. It works fine for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: Just copy the entire one line command to a text file. Replace the 5 "/path/to/film_n.avi"  and only them. Be really sure of every char on the paths you are using. Copy back and paste (CTRL+SHIFT+V) into your terminal.

Comment: Ty it is only one film first. Less chance to make errors :  while :; do vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/to/film_1.avi;done